# Avoiding a divide-by-zero situation in scheme

Tags: scheme, division

I'm tyring to make a function that divides two given numbers, then puts their quotient and the remainder in a list. I've gotten it to work except in certain cases. Here's the code I have:

```
(define (div dividend divisor)
  (cond ((= 0 divisor) #f)
    ((< dividend divisor) (cons (quotient divisor dividend) (cons  dividend '())))

(else
  (div (- dividend divisor) divisor))))
```

This works for most cases.

```
(div 13 4)   returns   '(4 1)
(div 3 7)   returns   '(2 3)
(div 5 0)   returns   #f  ;(returns false to avoid divide by zero situations)
```

All of these work perfectly, but ones such as:

```
(div 16 4)
(div 4 2)
(div 15 5)
```

All return the following error: **quotient: undefined for 0**
and this is focused on the code:

((< dividend divisor) (cons **(quotient divisor dividend)** (cons  dividend '())))

Is there any other way to build the list that I need? I need the list to contain the number of times the dividend goes into the divisor, and the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly checking the divisor for 0, but then you reverse it in `(quotient divisor dividend)`. The quotient of 13/4 is 3 with a remainder of 1 since 13 = 3*4 + 1.